Context menu item in test cases for Azure devops
Is it possible to create context menu item in Test suit under Test Point item

{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "",
    "publisher": "",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "name": "My First Extension",
    "description": "A sample Visual Studio Services extension",
    "public": false,
    "categories": ["Azure Test Plans"],
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
    ],
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "my-hub",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.menu",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-test-web.test-runs-menu"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "My Hub",
                "uri": "my-hub.html"
            }
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "my-hub.html",
            "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "node_modules/azure-devops-extension-sdk",
            "addressable": true,
            "packagePath": "lib"
        }
    ]
}

Edited: I have updated my question with confuguration file, I am pretty sure that categories is falls under Azure Test Plans

Can you provide a screenshot to show where do you want to add/insert the menu item to?

I've updated my question with screenshot, I wanted to add a option below Assign tester.

You can try to develop a menu action extension with Target ID "ms.vss-test-web.test-runs-menu". @vijaysai

Sure @BrightRan-MSFT

Please go ahead to try with an extension. @vijaysai

Have tried to develop an extension as the suggestion in my answer below? Does the Target ID "ms.vss-test-web.test-runs-menu" work for you? @vijaysai

I attempted it, but it was unsuccessful. Is there an alternative method?

I am afraid there is no alternative. Only extension can add the custom menu item. @vijaysai

To add an item to the menu of test points, you need to develop a menu action extension. And in the vss-extension.json file of the extension, the Target ID should be "ms.vss-test-web.test-runs-menu".
However, based on the documentation "Extensibility points", only the following Target IDs are listed as the available ones for Azure Test Plans menu and toolbar.

ms.vss-test-web.test-run-grid-menu
ms.vss-test-web.test-plans-suites-context
ms.vss-test-web.test-plan-pivot-tabs

You can try to use the Target ID "ms.vss-test-web.test-runs-menu" in your extension to see if it can work.
If it not work, you can try to report a feature request on Developer Community to ask adding this Target ID as the available one for extension development. This will make it more convenient for the Azure DevOps engineer teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

